# Python: how to download a file from an S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have some data stored in an `AWS` `S3` bucket.

If from terminal I do:

```
aws s3 ls s3://myBucket/folder/ --profile myProfile
2020-04-23 01:04:09   96858539 2020-01-01-file.csv.gz
```

If I try to download the file using `boto3`

```
import boto3
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='myProfile')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
f1 = '2020-01-01-file.csv.gz'
s3.meta.client.download_file('myBucket', 'folder/%s'%f1, f1)
```

I get the following error

```
ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **reason why it doesn't work for you** is that you create boto3 `session`

> session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='myProfile')

and you **do not use it**. So instead of `boto3.resource('s3')`, should try `session.resource('s3')`

But anyway, the boto3 docs have an entire section called [Downloading Files](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html). It shows two examples with explanation:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')
```

or

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open('FILE_NAME', 'wb') as f:
    s3.download_fileobj('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', f)
```